# Is it possible to (re)create a PDB file after a DLL is made

Tags: pdb-files

I have the DLL and I have the exact sources used to create the DLL. I want our local symbol server to work when we get a dump file from customers. (Updating the DLL at the customer site can't be done before the next patch/release of our product)

Comment: Did you try to recompile this dll file?

Comment: The debugger does not match the new PDB with the old DLL file

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That seems to be not possible. Have a look at this here: [Why does Visual Studio require debugger symbol files to *exactly* match the binary files that they were built with?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimgries/archive/2007/07/06/why-does-visual-studio-require-debugger-symbol-files-to-exactly-match-the-binary-files-that-they-were-built-with.aspx)

Or this article: [PDB Files: What Every Developer Must Know](https://www.wintellect.com/pdb-files-what-every-developer-must-know/)

Quote out of "PDB Files: What Every...":

> The extremely important part is how the debugger knows this is the
> exact matching PDB file for this binary. That's done through a GUID
> that's embedded in both the PDB file and the binary. If the GUID does
> not match, you certainly won't debug the module at the source code
> level.
> The .NET compiler, and for native the linker, puts this GUID into the
> binary and PDB. Since the act of compiling creates this GUID, stop and
> think about this for a moment. If you have yesterday's build and did
> not save the PDB file will you ever be able to debug the binary again?
> No! This is why it is so critical to save your PDB files for every
> build. Because I know you're thinking it, I'll go ahead and answer the
> question already forming in your mind: no, there's no way to change
> the GUID.

Comment: Looks like you are right. But it looks like chkmatch can be used in some cases: http://www.debuginfo.com/tools/chkmatch.html

Comment: Wow, interesting link! Ok, *usually* it is not possible. I hope that chkmatch can help you.